# lexical analysis gives only one output?

Tags: java, lexer, java-compiler-api

I tested [this example(**lexe.java**)](http://www.google.iq/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp11/lectures/lecture2/Lexer.java&ei=tFh7UpipH8zwhQfE8IGIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFfKdu-CYoAvHorTZpXHtzLqN4eyw&sig2=XbG3ZcDlEfTSsVW6DLGSzQ&bvm=bv.56146854,d.ZG4), but it gave me only one output.

I gave this text as a reader:

> ```
> public class LexeTest{
>  private int a = 14;
> }
> ```

And the **nextToken()** function is :

```
 public Category nextToken () {
        if (inp.findWithinHorizon (tokenPat, 0) == null)
            return Category.EOF;
        else {
            lastLexeme = inp.match ().group (0);
            if (inp.match ().start (1) != -1)
                return nextToken ();
            else if (inp.match ().start (2) != -1) 
                return Category.IDENT;
            else if (inp.match ().start (3) != -1)
                return Category.NUMERAL;
            Category result = tokenMap.get (lastLexeme);
            if (result == null)
                return Category.ERROR;
            else
                return result;
        }
    }
```

Isdie the main method:

`System.out.println(lexeObject.nextToken());`

output is :

> IDENT

Why? but the textfile contains multiple keywords? Anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that, but the problem seems to be your reading ability. Here is a part of the very first comment of the example you linked to (emphasis added by me):

> A Lexer produces a stream of tokens taken from an arbitrary Reader
>   supplied to the constructor, in response to **repeated** calls to the
>   Lexer's nextToken routine.

Comment: em, I didin't notice this. However, Please if you can just write to me the main, I tried a `do-while`, but I didn't success.

Comment: You want "the main"? Which one?

Comment: Yes, the main method how you call the `Lexer#nextToken()` in a loop, thanks

Comment: For example `while (lexer.nextToken() != Category.EOF);`

Answer (score 2):

If you only call `nextToken()` once, you will only get one token. I don't see why this is such a mystery. Try a *loop.*